# Gatt server service list is empty

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, bluetooth-gatt

I am new to BLE and I am trying to communicate from my android device to my pc running linux using BLE. I have added a service to the gatt server in my android device and I am advertising it. I am getting the server and I am able to access the characteristics inside the service from other android devices using applications like light blue and ble scanner. Howwever, when I am using bluetooth control the service and characteristics are not shown (list-attribute under menu gatt is empty). The bluetooth stack I am using is bluez 5.52.

Answer (score 0):

In order to populate the gatt services you must call `discoverServices` and let that complete. Once that call completes, then you will have access to your gatt services. I recommend using a library to help you called [Android BLE Library](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library), it is from Nordic Semiconductor and really helps out with all the nuances of BLE.